# Como inserir várias linhas de uma única consulta usando o mesmo ID

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando fazer múltiplos inserts usando o mesmo ID com o **Laravel** mas ele está fazendo apenas 1 insert.

**A idéia seria algo parecido com isso.**

```
ped_cod|est_cod|ped_qtde
    8  |2      |9
    8  |3      |2
    8  |4      |2
    8  |9      |15
```

**MODEL**

```
class EstoqueDet extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'public.estoque_det';
    protected $primaryKey = 'ped_cod';
}
```

**CONTROLLER** *(Verifico se o input está trazendo algo se Sim faço o insert)*

```
$caneta  = $this->request->get('caneta_input');
$sulfite = $this->request->get('sulfite_input');
$tonner = $this->request->get('tonner_input');
$pasta = $this->request->get('pasta_input');



$estoqdet = $this->estoqueDet; 


if(isset($caneta)) {

    $estoqdet->ped_cod = $pedido_id;
    $estoqdet->est_cod = $cod_caneta;
    $estoqdet->ped_qtde = $caneta;
    $estoqdet->save([$estoqdet]);



}

if(isset($sulfite)) {

    $estoqdet->ped_cod = $pedido_id;
    $estoqdet->est_cod = $cod_sulfite;
    $estoqdet->ped_qtde = $sulfite;
    $estoqdet->save([$estoqdet]);


}

if(isset($tonner)) {

    $estoqdet->ped_cod = $pedido_id;
    $estoqdet->est_cod = $cod_tonner;
    $estoqdet->ped_qtde = $tonner;
    $estoqdet->save([$estoqdet]);


}

if(isset($pasta)) {

    $estoqdet->ped_cod = $pedido_id;
    $estoqdet->est_cod = $cod_pasta;
    $estoqdet->ped_qtde = $pasta;
    $estoqdet->save([$estoqdet]);


}
```

Comment: Ele dá algum erro? Pode ser porque você não vai conseguir inserir mais de um registro com a mesma primary key, pois ela deve ser única.

Comment: Nao da nenhum erro na outra aplicacao que esta com o PHP estruturado ele insere tranquilo

Comment: Então tente tirar esta linha `protected $primaryKey = 'ped_cod';`

Comment: Eu tirei e ele comeca a dar o erro Undefined column: 7 ERRO: coluna "id" não existe

Comment: Bom, não sei se vc pode redefinir o banco, mas talvez seria interessante você criar a coluna `id` como primary key, e as outras como colunas normais. Neste caso iria inserir normalmente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você precisa criar uma nova instância a cada novo registro que deseja criar, no seu caso você está só alterando o mesmo registro N vezes.

```
if(isset($caneta)) {
    $estoqdet = new EstoqueDet();
    $estoqdet->ped_cod = $pedido_id;
    $estoqdet->est_cod = $cod_caneta;
    $estoqdet->ped_qtde = $caneta;
    $estoqdet->save([$estoqdet]);
}

if(isset($sulfite)) {
    $estoqdet = new EstoqueDet();
    $estoqdet->ped_cod = $pedido_id;
    $estoqdet->est_cod = $cod_sulfite;
    $estoqdet->ped_qtde = $sulfite;
    $estoqdet->save([$estoqdet]);
}
```

Comment: Perfeito @Jardel era isso mesmo obrigado!